# How to close a socket connection during pipe usage in Python

Tags: python, sockets, pipe

I am in such a scenario:

1. my script opens a socket connection to a remote database,
2. get an iterator (returned from executing a SQL statement against the remote database),
3. iterate the iterator and print the values

Since it is often that the SQL returns a lot of records, I often use the script in pipe fashion, i.e. `python script.py | head -10`. Of course I would have Socket error when I pipe it to `head`. The fix to the exception is:

```
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
```

My question is, in the case of pipe (e.g. `head -5`), does the database socket connection got closed automatically or properly? If not, how do I close it in my script for the case of pipe usage.

The code structure would look like this:

```
def getIter(n, conn):
  for i in xrange(n):
    yield i

def p(l):
  for x in l:
    print x

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # dbms_socket_conn.open() 

  # get iterator 
  ii = getIter(100, conn=None)
  p(ii)

  print "is the dbms connection got closed in case of pipe (e.g. head -5) ?"
  # dbms_socket_conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo could do something like:

```
try:
    # dbms_socket_conn.open() 

    # get iterator 
    ii = getIter(100, conn=None)
    p(ii)

    print "is the dbms connection got closed in case of pipe (e.g. head -5) ?"
finally:
    # dbms_socket_conn.close()
```

to ensure that your code execute the close method

EDIT:
The "head -5" only show the first 5 lines of the output but that doesn't mean that the script stops. If you try this:

```
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)

def getIter(n, conn):
  for i in xrange(n):
    yield i

def p(l):
  for x in l:
    print x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ii = getIter(100, conn=None)
        p(ii)
    finally:
        with open("test.txt","w") as f:
            f.write("asdasdasdasd")
```

You'll see that the files is written, that means the finally clause is executed. You should put there the dbms_socket_conn.close()

Comment: I don't think it works for the pipe case. The evaluation does not reach the `finally` statements at all in case of pipe (e.g. `python script.py | head -5`).

Comment: Oh that's odd, if you look in [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) it say "A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not..." 
if the script stops because of the pipe, it should throw an exception or something like that and then execute the finally statement.

Comment: No it does not throw exception with pipe. Try the code in the OP, and do `python script.py | head -5`, it won't throw exception, which I think it is good, but need a way for the script to know it is "pipe-finished" so the connection can be closed.

Comment: You are absolutely correct: "The "head -5" only show the first 5 lines of the output but that doesn't mean that the script stops." For whatever reason, I thought `pipe` would also terminate the program that is being piped (here, the `script.py`) when appropriate. I thought `pipe` would be a practical way to tune the script. In the database case, assuming a query yielding 1 Million records, I thought `| head -10` would terminating the query once 10 records (or whatever the Database connection cache size is) fetched, thus avoiding further RPCs.